# Integrability based on continuity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

> Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)= \begin{cases} 
>       a_n,& \text{if }x= \frac{1}{n}, n\in\mathbb{N} \\
>       0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ where $a_n$ is bounded sequence always larger than zero. Investigate the function for integrability.

I know that a function is riemann integrable if it is monotone. For this case we can choose $x_1=\frac{1}{4} , x_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt2},x_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt5},x_4=\frac{1}{2}$ to show that $x_1<x_3<x_4<x_2$ with $f(x_3)=0<f(x_1)$, $f(x_2)=0<f(x_4).$ From this it follows that $f$ isn't monotone so not necessarily integrable . The second part is where I'm having trouble, if a function is continuous on an interval it is said to be riemann integrable but considering that we've only been given that $a_n$ is bounded and nothing else I don't know how to proceed. Is the function simply discontinuous everywhere? I'd appreciate some help about this.

Comment: Function have countable points of discontinuous.

Comment: Tip: Lebesgue integrability criterion.

Comment: The function is integrable for any $a<b$. To prove that, one can prove that all lower Darbux sums are $0$, and that the upper Darboux sums can be made arbitrarily close to $0$ by a clever choice of the partition of $[a,b]$. In particular if $0\in[a,b]$ you may need to choose a tiny interval starting with $0$ and a lot of tiny intervals around points $1/n$ not covered by the first interval. I will leave it to you to fill the gaps in this proof.

Comment: @user7427029 You have to appreciate that, if the OP is doing a problem of this sort, they are probably learning *Riemann* integrability, which means they are unlikely to be able to apply the *Lebesgue* integrability criterion at their stage.

Comment: @StinkingBishop In fairness the Lebesgue criterion he's quoting refers to Riemann integrability, not Lebesgue integrability, and in this case it works very similarly to the Darboux criterion you're quoting.

Comment: @StephenDonovan The Lebesgue criterion: "A bounded function on a compact interval $[a, b]$ is Riemann integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere (the set of its points of discontinuity has measure zero, in the sense of **Lebesgue measure**)." (emphasis mine). To apply it, one needs to understand *Lebesgue measure*, full stop. (OK, perhaps I am exaggerating a bit, you may only know some basic facts about it, but the point is that Lebesgue measure and Lebesgue integral are normally taught together, both *after* Riemann integration.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop: Fair point. I myself had the opportunity to have this criterion without further Lebesgue measure theory in the Analysis lecture I heard. (only in the weakened, but likely-named form: countable many discontinuities => Riemann integrability) Props at zkutch for bringing it up in the first comment.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I agree in terms of them being taught at different times, but with the understanding that the Lebesgue measure is really about covering a set with intervals, I still think the two methods are essentially similar here. Also I share the experience of having used this criterion before more in-depth measure theory (but in my case it likely has more to me self-studying)

Comment: @StinkingBishop The argument made sense in my head and cleared most things so thank you.

Comment: If it really did help, you may want to answer your own question here. (Which is BTW encouraged on MSE.)